Is there any way to edit the contrast/brightness of font in the Visual Studio Code Editor?
I'm trying to adjust the font appearance in Visual Studio Code's editor to be more similar to PHPStorm. In PHPStorm, the font has a dimmer look that's easier on my eyes. In contrast, Visual Studio Code's font color feels too bright and high contrast.
I've searched the settings but haven't found an option for adjusting overall contrast or brightness. I am currently using the Darcula color theme.
This is what my VS Code looks like:
VS Code
And this is what I would like to achieve:
PHPStorm

Yes, you can custom adjust text colours using settings.js of your vscode profile.

They will all go inside editor.tokenColorCustomizations.
You will need to find out what token exactly you need to update. For that you can use "CTRL + TAB + i" on each different word (like function, strings, variables etc).
You need to put full hex with alpha (like #ee684742) as colour value.

For example, on a python script I try "ctrl + tab + i" and I get this:

This tell me the language, and the textmate scopes that are applied.
Here is an example of what can go inside editor.tokenColorCustomizations:
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": { 
        "comments": "#727272",
        "strings": "#e70000",
        "keywords": "#0000FF",
        "types": "#192c55ee",

        "textMateRules": [
            //Python specific
            {
                "scope": "string.quoted.docstring.multi.python",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#d400ffe5",
                }
            },
            //yml specific (another example)
            {
                "scope": [
                    "string.unquoted.plain.out.yaml",
                    "string.quoted.single.xml",
                    "string.quoted.double.xml"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#E70000",
                }
            }
        ]
}

For more details, see https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars

if you customize do it for a specific theme, tokenColorCustomizations has no need to read the TM grammar rules
